# How big was the white prison in THX1138?

Tags: thx-1138

How big was the white prison in THX1138, which seemed in the middle of nowhere?  In their escape from the "prison" there was a long walk, so much so that they brought extra food rations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The implication, at least in the [novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/267301.THX_1138), is that the white prison is *large*, but not astonishingly so. When he finally reaches the door, THX realises that his perception of the prison was being skewed in some way and **the sides and edges deliberately hidden from him**.

> The whole blank background of nothingness seemed to change as a camera
> changes focus, bringing objects that were blurred into invisibility
> suddenly into clear, sharp view.
>
> There was a door, flanked on both sides by flashing varicolored
> lights! And it was set into a metal bulkhead, with steel ribs
> protruding from it and rivets in the ribs. THX put out a hand to feel
> its reality.
>
> “What… what… how can it be?” He heard SEN breathless behind him.
>
> **“They must have done something to the way we see,” THX said
> uncertainly. “They did something to our eyes…”**
>
> **“Or maybe the food cubes were drugged,” SEN suggested.**
>
> **“Or hypnosis.”**